# How to remove a button created by pygbutton

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to remove a button created by [PygButton](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/10/30/creating-a-button-ui-module-for-pygame/). I have created it as such:

```
button1 = pygbutton.PygButton((50, 50, 60, 30), '1')
button2 = pygbutton.PygButton((120, 50, 60, 30), '2')
button3 = pygbutton.PygButton((190, 50, 60, 30), '3')
allButtons = (button1,button2,button3)

for b in allButtons:
    b.draw(screen)
```

However, once a button is clicked, I would like to clear the buttons in the screen and show something else on the screen.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea that I thought of was to make a new screen after a button has been pressed.

Basically, I have a bool that I called `buttonhasbeenpressed`. Until a button has been pressed, we're just checking to see if the `event` was a button press. After it's been pressed, we set the bool to `True`, "clear" the background (by creating a new screen over the old one), and then continue doing whatever else we'd like. My example code only "removes" the buttons, changes the background color, and changes the caption on the window, but you can use this idea to change whatever you want about the state of your game post-button press.

Here's the example, which you should be able to run on your machine to test.

```
import pygame,pygbutton
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#Create the "Pre Button Press Screen"
width = 1024
height = 768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])
pygame.display.set_caption('OLD SCREEN NAME')
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((250, 250, 250))
screen.blit(background, [0,0])
pygame.display.flip()
button1 = pygbutton.PygButton((50, 50, 60, 30), '1')
button2 = pygbutton.PygButton((120, 50, 60, 30), '2')
button3 = pygbutton.PygButton((190, 50, 60, 30), '3')
buttonhasbeenpressed = False

def screenPostButtonPress():
    width = 1024
    height = 768
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width,height])
    pygame.display.set_caption('NEW SCREEN NAME!!!!!!!')
    background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill((20, 20, 40))
    screen.blit(background, [0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    #buttons not on screen after a button has been pressed

def waitingForButtonClick():
    allButtons = [button1,button2,button3]        
    buttonevent1 = button1.handleEvent(event)
    buttonevent2 = button2.handleEvent(event)
    buttonevent3 = button3.handleEvent(event)

    for b in allButtons:
        b.draw(screen)

    if 'click' in buttonevent1 or 'click' in buttonevent2 or 'click' in buttonevent3:
        return False
    return True

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #Wait for a button to be pressed, once one has, "clear" the screen by creating a new screen
    if buttonhasbeenpressed == False and waitingForButtonClick() == False:
       buttonhasbeenpressed = True
       screenPostButtonPress()
    pygame.display.update()
```